# Jacoco Websphere

Tags: jenkins, websphere, jacoco

Using RAD I can use Jacoco to get code coverage reports for my websphere application code. I need to be able to use Jacoco with a build of websphere that does not have an IDE.

I have a remote machine running websphere, tests are performed on the webserver using jenkins, before each test the server is stopped using `stopServer.bat`, and shut down after each test using `stopServer.bat`. Both batch files are provided with the websphere application.

In the generic jvm arguments I have placed my --javaagent.

How can I start a stand alone websphere server with jacoco? Do I edit the `startServer.bat`? is there a command line call I make? I have been searching for a while now.

This is my genericJVM arguments

```
-Xshareclasses:none -javaagent:C:\eclemma-2.3.2\jacocoagent.jar=output=file,destfile=C:\eclemma-2.3.2\jacoco.exec
```

This is the contents of runServer.bat

```
@REM runServer.bat
@REM Generated: Tue Jun 30 10:44:58 CDT 2015

@setlocal
@echo off

@REM Bootstrap values ...
cd C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin
call "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin\setupCmdLine.bat"
@REM For debugging the server process:
@REM set DEBUG=-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777

@REM Environment Settings
SET PATH=%WAS_PATH%


@REM Launch Command
"C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/bin/java"  %DEBUG% "-Declipse.security" "-Dosgi.install.area=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer" "-Dosgi.configuration.area=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/configuration" "-Dosgi.framework.extensions=com.ibm.cds,com.ibm.ws.eclipse.adaptors" "-Xshareclasses:name=webspherev70,nonFatal" "-Xscmx50M" "-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=250" "-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext/ibmorb.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext/ibmext.jar" "-classpath" "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar" "-Dibm.websphere.internalClassAccessMode=allow" "-verbose:gc" "-Xms512m" "-Xmx1024m" "-Dws.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/web/help;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime" "-Dderby.system.home=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/derby" "-Dcom.ibm.itp.location=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/bin" "-Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true" "-Duser.install.root=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01" "-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder" "-Dwas.install.root=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer" "-Dpython.cachedir=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/temp/cachedir" "-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager" "-Dserver.root=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01" "-Dcom.ibm.security.jgss.debug=off" "-Dcom.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug=off" "-Xshareclasses:none" "-javaagent:C:\eclemma-2.3.2\jacocoagent.jar=output=file,destfile=C:\eclemma-2.3.2\" "-Xverbosegclog:C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/logs/server1/verbosegc.txt,10,1000" "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties/wsjaas.conf" "-Djava.security.policy=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties/server.policy" "com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher" "-nosplash" "-application" "com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher" "com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer" "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config" "jsf1Node01Cell" "jsf1Node01" "server1"

@endlocal
```

Comment: Adding the `-javaagent` to generic JVM arguments should cause `startServer.bat` to start the server JVM with JaCoCo.  Are you saying that did not work for some reason?  Did the server fail to start, or did jacoco.exec not get written, or what's the actual problem?  I'm not sure what you mean by "stand alone"; are you drawing a distinct between base and ND, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Maybe I am using stand alone incorrectly, by that I mean the websphere server does not run in an IDE, it is a windows service. The .exec file is not being created.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks.  You could try running `bin/startServer.bat server1 -script runServer.bat`, which should generate a runServer.bat script that contains all the arguments that will be used to actually launch the server JVM.  Does that contain your configured `-javaagent`?  If yes, please show it.  If not, then your generic JVM arguments aren't configured.

Comment: In the file near the end there is the line -javaagent:C:\eclemma-2.3.2\jacocoagent.jar=output=file,destfile=C:\eclemma-2.3.2\, so does this mean my agent is set up correctly

Comment: `destfile=` should be a file, not a directory.  There's probably an error message in `native_stderr.log`

Comment: ok so I changed the jvm arguments to point to jacoco.exec, does this file need to exist already?

Comment: No, but if it does, then the JaCoCo runtime will append by default (you can disable with `append=false`).  If that resolved the problem, let me know and I'll add an actual answer that you can accept.

Comment: I am going to test it now

Comment: turns out, I was trying to write to a tcpserver, changing it to file and setting a file name worked!

Comment: Are you flushing the coverage data only after you shutdown the instance or you dont need to shutdown your websphere instance? In my case, I use Tomcat and when I start tomcat, it creates jacocoXX.exec file (IT for IT tests, AT for Acceptance tests etc), the file is created as soon as Tomcat JVM starts as I'm passing jacocoagent.jar with other jacoco parameters to Tomcat's startTomcat.sh script or in OPTS.. but code coverage data is flushed only when we stop the Tomcat instance. Until that happens if u use the destfile jacoco exec file, you wont see any coverage info (green/red/yelllow)

Comment: I use code to request a dump and save that as a file